# dojo stop dropdown button from closing on checkbox select

Tags: javascript, html, dojo

here is the html:

```
<button data-dojo-attach-point="pinFilterButton" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/DropDownButton">
    <span>Proj. PIN</span>
    <select multiple="true" name="multiselect" data-dojo-attach-point="pinFilter" data-dojo-type="dojox.form.CheckedMultiSelect"></select>
</button>
```

I just want to stop the dropdown from closing when a checkbox is selected.

Here is what I tried:

```
on(t.pinFilterButton.dropDownContainer, 'close', function (e) {
    e.stopPropogation();
})
```

among other variations.

Comment: it si stopPropagation , but what you really need is preventDefault

Comment: I'm pretty sure `stopPropagation` *would* be correct for typical DOM events, but I'm not sure that `close` is emitted as a DOM event, in which case I expect it won't have any effect.  `preventDefault` is worth a try if that particular event is cancelable but I'm not sure what to expect there.

Comment: Yeah preventDefault didnt work either

Comment: Could you put together a jsfiddle? *Seems like* you'd want to stop propagation for the click event on a given row after it was de/selected, not stop the close event from bubbling up.